# How can I make users make payments via Stripe rather than my Wordpress site?

Tags: java, html, wordpress, stripe-payments

I've built a page on my Wordpress website that has the ability for users to choose a subscription offer, which currently looks like this:
[image]

What I'm aiming to do is when a user clicks on any of the subscribe buttons, they're redirected to a Stripe page that can take all of their details and payment of the option they require, like PayPal does. Thing is all I can see are instructions as to how to integrate Stripe into my webpage which then makes things a lot more complicated (SSL's etc). So does anyone know how I can implement what I am aiming to? 
I have created a Stripe account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe doesn't offer hosted payment pages like Paypal does.  There are a number of third party Stripe integrations that [offer subscription management services](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations#recurring-payments), and a number of [Stripe plugins for Wordpress](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=stripe) that might help you solve this.